# Is one-to-one correspondence the same as bijection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

Or is it a bijection that is everywhere defined ?

Comment: Yes; see [Bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

Comment: Depends on the context, what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: One to one correspondence and  bijection are synonymous

Comment: @TomCarter for A = {1,2,3} and B = {a,b}, is { (1,a), (2,b) } a bijection from A to B ?

Comment: No, it is not. In a bijection "there are no unpaired elements". Please, read the provided definition.

Comment: But mind you, a *1-1 map* is just an injective map.

Comment: one word answer: yes.

Answer (score -3):

I believe there is a subtle difference between a bijection and a one-to-one-correspondence, especially in popular math treatments of set theory. The difference being that a one-to-one-correspondence between two sets is sometimes drawn with two-directional arrows that relate elements of the two sets. A bijection, being a mapping, is usually depicted with one-directional arrows or rays relating the elements. In the former case the distinction between the domain and range is not really meaningful, whilst in the latter case it is meaningful and we call the sets domain and co-domain respectively. It seems that according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) a one-to-one correspondence is a bijection, so one-directional arrows are appropriate. Though the distinction between rays and double sided arrows is not important since the inverse relation is also a bijection.

I am afraid we may just be splitting hairs here.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Which part is incorrect? Here is an example of a one to one correspondance with two sided arrows, https://images.app.goo.gl/zfz2PEe9BsrXPmHw8
I understand in the context of mappings or functions, a one to one correspondence is a bijection.

Comment: Not very useful comment above.