# Dedekind infinite set definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading a book about elementary set theory, and I've found this defenition:
[image]

I have two questions:

**Question 1:**
Why one-to-one correspondence were assumed to be equal to injection?

**Question 2:**
Why we say $f:X\to X$ is an injection ? It cannot be bijection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is common in English literature to use one-to-one as synonymous with injective. Anyways, even if it meant that $f:X\to Y$ is bijective, the hypothesis $Y\subsetneq X$ would make it equivalent to $f:X\to X$ being injective and not surjective nevertheless.
2. Since $f(X)\subsetneq X$ is a hypothesis, bijectivity of $f$ is impossible.

Comment: I saw via this link that one-to-one correspondence is equal to bijective too :) . Why thats confusing?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420054/is-one-to-one-correspondence-the-same-as-bijection

Comment: @program_craft Ah, ok, so some lunatic decided that one-to-one *correspondence* is bijective function and one-to-one *function* is injective function. I didn't know that, mostly because you come by it in the phrase "Let $f:X\to Y$ be one-to-one et cetera", where one-to-one means injective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a one-to-one correspondence is an injective function. And no, it cannot be a bijection, because while a bijection is an injection, the requirement from $f$ is that $f(X)$ is a proper subset of $X$, or in other words: $f$ is not a surjection.

---

For example, $\Bbb N$ is a Dedekind-infinite set, since $f(x)=x+1$ is an injection which is not a surjection. In contrast, $\{0,1\}$ is not Dedekind-infinite, since there are only two injective functions $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$ and $g(0)=1,g(1)=0$ and they are both surjective.